# How can I provide an iPhone app that will be integrated into a customer's project without providing the source code?

Tags: iphone

I would like to provide my client a native iPhone application module that he could integrate within his own iPhone application.

I don't want to provide the source code.

How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Build your code as a static library and send it to them.

http://blog.stormyprods.com/2008/11/using-static-libraries-with-iphone-sdk.html